# Grouping by date in PHP MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database that looks like this:

```
id             |          Title           |        Timestamp
-------------------------------------------------------------
0                         Test 1                     2013-02-26 00:00:00
1                         Test 2                     2013-02-26 00:00:00
2                         Test 3                     2013-02-29 00:00:00
3                         Test 4                     2013-03-31 00:00:00
```

I want to select them and output them in groupings like this:

```
Tomorrow
Test 1
Test 2

This Week
Test 3

And Beyond
Test 4
```

I need the MySQL and PHP to output it, I can't figure it out.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/) See [ask advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice), please.

Comment: `group by` can take arbitrary logic, not just field names. so... `group by logic_to_calculate_tomorrow, logic_to_calculate_next_week, etc...`

Comment: for today:
SELECT * FROM table WHERE CURDATE() < timestamp_column AND timestamp_column < DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 day); for the rest - fix it yourself

Comment: Feel free to consult PHP's [`mysqli` documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php), you can start with `mysqli_query(), mysqli_fetch_row(), mysqli_fetch_array(), mysqli_fetch_assoc()` and the functions mentioned in the 'See also' sections.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a `CASE` expression with the [`Week()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week) and [`Day()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_day) functions:

```
select title,
  case 
    when week(timestamp) = week(curdate())
      then 
        case 
          when day(timestamp) = day(curdate()) +1
          then 'Tomorrow'
          else 'This Week'
        end 
    when week(timestamp) > week(curdate())
      then 'And Beyond'
  end as Col
from yourtable
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8a45b/6).

Or this could be written as:

```
select title,
  case 
    when week(timestamp) = week(curdate())
        and day(timestamp) = day(curdate()) +1
      then 'Tomorrow'
    when week(timestamp) = week(curdate())
      then 'This Week'
    else 'And Beyond'
  end as Col
from yourtable
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8a45b/7)

This returns:

```
|  TITLE |        COL |
-----------------------
| Test 1 |   Tomorrow |
| Test 2 |   Tomorrow |
| Test 3 |  This Week |
| Test 4 | And Beyond |
```

Comment: What would the PHP be to output this?

Comment: @Talon sorry, I don't know PHP. This is a sql solution that can be used to return the data to your application.

Comment: @Talon My suggestion would be to post another question with your PHP code and then ask how you would incorporate this in your application.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need a case statement in your select clause to create a calculated field which you can then group by.

```
SELECT `id`, `title`, `timestamp`,
    (CASE
        WHEN timestamp < DATEADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY THEN 'Tomorrow'
        ELSE WHEN timestamp < DATEADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK THEN 'This week'
        ELSE 'Beyond'
    END) AS `timeframe`
FROM table
ORDER BY `timestamp` ASC
```

Note here I am taking advantage of the sort order for the timestamp, which will create a logic grouping for you.

Comment: Do you know the PHP to Output this?

Comment: @Talon Yes I would know how to output in PHP.  However, you should try to learn it and do it yourself, and come back and ask specific questions if you run into problems.